# Is there any way i can use google duplex in my project/or there is any Api available regarding that

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, duplex, google-assist-api, assistant

i want to use google duplex service in my app and web and use its result into my app to make some appointment or some thing like that.
how i can impliment it.is there any api available or not?

Answer (score 0):

Google Duplex does not have an API for developers to access.